# Why the compiler does not raise an error when not passing address of array element?

Tags: c++, arrays, macos, pointers, reference

I have the following code

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void show (int list[], int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        cout << list[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void swap (int* a, int* b) {
    cout << *a << ' ' <<  *b << endl;
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
    cout << *a << ' ' <<  *b << endl;
}

void aFunction (int list[], int len) {
    cout << "From aFunction ";
    show(list, len);
    swap(list[0], list[1]);
    cout << "From aFunction ";
    show(list, len);
}

int main() {
    int list[] = {6, 4};
    int len = sizeof(list)/sizeof(int);
    aFunction(list, len);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this I do not get any errors and I receive the output as

```
From aFunction 6 4 
From aFunction 4 6
```

But when I change the following line in `aFunction`

```
swap(list[0], list[1]);
```

to

```
swap(&list[0], &list[1]);
```

it still compiles and give me the following output

```
From aFunction 6 4 
6 4
4 6
From aFunction 4 6
```

What is going on? My initial thought was `swap(list[0], list[1])` is right since arrays decay to pointers when passed to a function so we are essentially passing pointers to `swap` but then the `cout` in `swap` is not printed, which leads me to believe `swap(&list[0], &list[1])` is right. If the latter is right, why the compiler does not raise any error for the first and why the `cout` in `swap` does not execute? Which one is right? What's going on????? I am compiling this program using `g++ weird.cpp` on a MacBook Pro. I would be really grateful for an explanation.

Comment: You're calling [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) because of `using namespace std;` not your `swap` function.  Yet another reason not to pull all of the `std` namespace into the global namespace like that.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Something is still not clear. Why/How is `list[0]` an `int` in `aFunction` when `list[]` is passed as an array to pointer when passing it to `aFunction`? If arrays are passed to functions as pointer then shouldn't `list[0]` in `aFunction` be of pointer to int type?

Comment: @PapaDelta arrays can't be passed around by value, only by pointer/reference. In this case, the `int list[]` parameter of `aFunction()` is interpreted as `int* list`, so `list[n]` is the same as `*(list + n)`, which is an `int` (actually an `int&`). In `main()`, passing the `list` array to `aFunction()` will decay into an `int*` pointer to the 1st element.

Comment: @RemyLebeau so every time I use `list[n]` in the function, it (`list + n`) is automatically getting dereferenced to `*(list+n)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), not your own `swap` function.

`std::swap` takes two reference arguments of any matching type.

(This is why, IMHO, `using namespace std;` can be a bad idea. I prefer to qualify names with `std::` explicitly.)

Comment: Confirmed by viewing disassembly: https://godbolt.org/z/8s7onz7Wc

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Something is still not clear. Why/How is `list[0]` an `int` in `aFunction` when `list[]` is passed as an array to pointer when passing it to `aFunction`? If arrays are passed to functions as pointer then shouldn't `list[0]` in `aFunction` be of pointer to int type?

Comment: @PapaDelta I suggest reading section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). C and C++ have similar rules.